# Using HeidiSQLs remote db as xampps db

Tags: database, apache, xampp, heidisql

In a previous environment I was able to start Apache in xampp and open up a connection to a remote db in heidiSQL and Apache would now use my remote db as its db.

In my current DB it seems that I'm having trouble setting this up.

The error I'm getting is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I know that in my old environment I didn't have to change any of my source code to get this to work. I just want to know if I need to put something in php.ini or somewhere else to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the port number. I changed the port in heidiSQL from 3307 to 3306 and it works now.